# Python, how to convert spline defined by x;y list of point into NURB curve

Tags: python, numpy, nurbs

is possible to convert the (x;y) coordinates system into a **NURBS** definition control points and knots?

The main idea is that I'm trying to develop a modeling tool in python for air wind generator and I want mathematically model the blades as a **NURBS** surfaces, but the curves that defines the blade transversal sections are normalized into (x;y) coordinates files.

Now I have all the (x;y) points defined into 2D Numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain that you need NURBS surfaces? As far as I can tell,
their primary advantage over b-spline surfaces is that they can precisely model
circular arcs. I've worked with airfoils for many years, and arcs aren't something
that are particularly useful to me.

Anyway, romeric is correct when he states that there is nothing analogous to `scipy.interpolate.splprep` for surfaces.
But if you're not against rolling your own, you can create a 3D array
from your section data of shape (3, m, n), where 'm' is the number of points per section, 'n' is the
number of sections, and the first dimension holds x, y, and z values on the m x n grid.
Once you have that, you can use `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` to create 
3 separate 2D parametric surfaces for the x, y and z coordinates. Then write
a class to combine these into a single 2D surface in 3D space, so that when you call 
`mysurf.ev(0.5, 0.2)` for instance, it evaluates the 3 `RectBivariateSpline`
instances embedded in your class and returns an (x, y, z) coordinate.

I've posted a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/subnivean/c622cc2b58e6376263b8) that may get you started. To try it, either run it from the command line, or do this:

```
from bsplinesurf import DemoBSplineSurf
srf = DemoBSplineSurf()
srf.plot()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `scipy.interpolate` for this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10) # x-coordinates
y = np.sin(x) # y-coordinates
tck = splrep(x, y) # get bspline representation given (x,y) values
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 200) # new set of values, just to check
y2 = splev(x2, tck) # evaluate the y values of new coordinates on NURBS curve
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x2, y2) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

The tuple `tck` contains your knot vector and control points (coefficients). There are also more involved routines in SciPy, look [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Note that these are only for bspline curves. As far as I know there are no equivalent methods for surfaces in SciPy. If you want to use surfaces, depending on your requirement, you can either use [igakit](https://petiga-igakit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
from igakit.cad import ruled, circle
c1 = circle(angle=(0,np.pi/2.))
c2 = circle(radius=2,angle=(0,np.pi/2.))
print "knot vector:", c1.knots
print "control points:", c1.control
srf = ruled(c1,c2)
plt.plot(srf)
plt.show() 

knot vector: (array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),)
control points: array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00],
   [  7.07106781e-01,   7.07106781e-01,   0.00000000e+00, 7.07106781e-01],
   [  2.22044605e-16,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

[image]

or the [NURBS package](http://runten.tripod.com/NURBS/). For fancier stuff [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) and [Salome](http://www.salome-platform.org/) have complete Python API for all family of NURBS curves/surfaces with the latter being based on [OpenCascade](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core).